# Magento 1.9 Shipping methods not showing in checkout or frontend but they show on backend {orders}

Tags: magento-1.9

Hello Dear sir or madams,

My magento 1.9 store is configured for free shipping but in the check out I get:
Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.

Also no shipping options appear in the shopping cart or frontend but in backend, I see free shipping in the orders.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks